# MVC 5 RouteConfig trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have such action:

```
[ObjectRequired]
public ActionResult Campaign(int? id, SomeClass object = null)
{
    ...
}
```

What i need is to route to this action:

a) with only int parameter (.../Campaign/12345)

b) with no parametes (optionally) (.../Campaign)

MVC error says, that there is no nonparametric constructor (if delete "object" parameter - it's ok). But i cant delete "object" parameter, because i need to check some values and pass value from [ObjectRequired] attribute like this:

```
filterContext.ActionParameters["object"] = _someObject;
```

I don't want to use constructions like ViewData. Where's the right way?

Comment: How are you doing your routing? Is it through a config or attributes?

Comment: Routing is default, through config. I've tried throw attributes, but it didn't help.

Comment: routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what I'm about to say but I'll say it as if I am...

**You can't pass an object through to a get**. You could pass back parameters and use a **custom route handler** to build the object for you.

You could also hold the object in data and use **Entity Framework** to get the model.

You could also use **TempData**, but that's similar to **ViewData**.

You could also hold it in their **Session**.

Comment: I can easily change existing parameter in OnActionExecuting. For example, i can change id parameter value. So, i just need route ".../Controller/Campaign/123" to my action. Object parameter is null by default and i'm changing it's value in OnActionExecuting. I think, it's must be some way...